# Metaplex createMetadataAccountV3 How to Populate Context

Tags: solana, metaplex, phantom-wallet

I'm trying to utilize the @metaplex-foundation/umi library and came across an issue when setting up the context and invoking the createMetadataAccountV3 function:

```
const umi = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi');

let myContext = umi.createNullContext();
let myTransaction = metaPlex.createMetadataAccountV3(
    myContext,
    CreateMetadataAccountV3Args
);
```

While attempting the above, I consistently receive the following error:

```
InterfaceImplementationMissingError: Tried using ProgramRepositoryInterface but no implementation of that interface was found. Make sure an implementation is registered, e.g. via "context.programs = new MyProgramRepository();".
```

The SDK documentation suggests using:

```
context.programs = new MyProgramRepository();
```

However, it's not entirely clear to me how to properly implement this. Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly populate myContext and address this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer under umi docs.

Not a fan of umi....but it is what it is.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/umi/blob/main/docs/installation.md

```
const myUmi= require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults');

const umi = myUMI.createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

let CreateMetadataAccountV3Args = {
        //accounts
        metadata: metadataAccount,
        mint: polaris_exp_mintKeypair.publicKey,
        mintAuthority: pdaPublicKey,
        payer: feePayerAccount.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: pdaPublicKey,
        // & instruction data
    data: {
      name: "myname",
      symbol: "exp",
      uri: "example_uri.com",
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
      creators: null,
      collection: null,
      uses: null
    },
    isMutable: true,
    collectionDetails: null,
  }

  const umi = myUMI.createUmi('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

  let myTransaction = metaPlex.createMetadataAccountV3(
    umi,
    CreateMetadataAccountV3Args
  )

  console.log(myTransaction)
```

Comment: is the metadataAccount just the publicKey of the newly generated keypair?

Comment: metaDataAccount is a PDA with these seeds [metaData, tokenMetaDataPID,mint]

Comment: https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts

Answer (score 2):

If you are using umi framework (since "@metaplex-foundation/js" is deprecated), for most contexts you have to pass the defaults from "@metaplex-foundation/js" package. Providing a null context just doesn't provide what the transaction requires.

I know UMI is a bit complex but thats the accepted way now.

So to modify your code:

```
const { createUmi } = require("@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults");
// other imports

// Use the RPC endpoint of your choice.
const RPC_ENDPOINT = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";

const umi = createUmi(RPC_ENDPOINT);

let myTransaction = metaPlex.createMetadataAccountV3(
    umi,
    CreateMetadataAccountV3Args //You need to create this entire type
);
```

@azuldev has already shown how to create the `CreateMetadataAccountV3Args` so not repeating it here just wanted to clear that wherever context is required use umi defaults.